# SVG content rendering outside viewBox?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to use SVG to graph some data.  My timestamps are relatively long integers (at least ten digits).  To my understanding, if I have data from t<sub>min</sub> to t<sub>max</sub> with measurements ranging from y<sub>min</sub> to y<sub>max</sub>, my viewbox should be

```html
<svg viewBox=" t_min   y_min  (t_max-t_min) (y_max-y_min)" />
<!--          [x_min] [y_min]    [width]       [height]   -->
```

For small values, it *seems* to hold well enough, though the wacky output could reveal already that I'm misunderstanding something.

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none"
     width="500" height="300"
     viewBox="6000 -5 3600 10">
  <line x1="6000" y1="-5"
        x2="9600" y2="5"
        stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

With large values though, things break down :-(  What am I doing wrong?

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none"
     width="500" height="300"
     viewBox="5573826000 -5 3600 10">
  <line x1="5573826000" y1="-5"
        x2="5573829600" y2="5"
        stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The underlying graphics libraries that browsers use don't really support really large values and there's not that much call for them to do so. Chrome, Safari and Firefox are all open source so if you wanted to fix them the power is in your hands.

Comment: @RobertLongson If it is indeed not possible, then that's probably the only good answer :-( Naturally, I'm stuck supporting IE.

Comment: So scale your data before plotting it. I.e. subtract some delta from your timestamps so they aren't all really long integers.

Comment: For what it's worth, librsvg and Inkscape have no problem with these values. So you could at least convert them to PNG.